# DateTime modify current date to get last day of the year?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Say I already have an arbitrary start date:

`$start = DateTime('2015-02-08')`

I now want to clone and modify it to fast forward it to the end of the year:

```
$start = DateTime('2018-02-08');
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('end of year');
```

Obviously `end of year` won't work, but it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish. I know there are ways to solve this, but I was wondering if there was a clean way to modify it without re-building a new date from the `$start` DateTime object.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work with the modify() function.

```
$start = new \DateTime('2018-02-08');
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('last day of december this year');
echo $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the date to be December 31st using `$start` to get the year:

```
$end->setDate($start->format("Y"), 12, 31);
```

although you can also `$end->format("Y")` as well.

Comment: I know I can do that (and what I'll probably end up doing), I'm asking because that modify parameter will come from an input form - a user will have a list of ending periods to choose from ('To end of week', 'To end of month', 'To end of quarter', 'To end of year'), and I was hoping for a super clean way to just pass that in to `modify()` somehow, rather than using a switch statement and some logic.

Comment: Unfortunately that gets too arbitrary to do "cleanly". A switch statement is as good as it gets (or some array gimmickery).